# Is it possible to migrate projects on SONAR from the in-memory DB to an Oracle DB?

Tags: sonarqube

I am currently setting up SONAR with the in-memory db for an evaluation. Should we wish to use the tool, I would like to then migrate the analysis results onto an Oracle db to use going forward. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tool is provided to do such a migration, and I advise you not to try to do so.

However, be aware that you will have the possibility to replay the history of your analysis: you can check out old versions of your code and launch an analysis on each one using the "sonar.projectDate" paramater to change the date.